# Root persistent disk and non-root persistent disk in google cloud persistent disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, disk

In GCP I came across creating disks and attaching them to a VM. There are two terms:

1. root persistent disks
2. non-root persistent disks

According to my understanding:

**root persistent disks** contain the OS images and these can be used (boot files)

**non-root persistent disks**  are created such that applications use them for their operational purposes

If I mount the same root persistent disk to two different VMs, and after that if I make modifications to the system files in root persistent disk and reboot both the VMs, does the changes get applied in both of the VMs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach one root (boot) disk to more than one VM -- that's a 1-to-1 relationship.

You can create multiple VMs from the same *image*, but that creates copies of the image on independent disks.

Comment: (However, you can attach a non-boot disk to two different VMs, if you mount it read only at both locations.)